# Nhibernate Profiler - Shows no information other than "session"?

Tags: nhibernate

So I am having problems getting NHibernate intergated in my MVC project.  I therefore, installed the NHProfiler and initialized it in the Global.asax.cs file (NhibernateProfiler.Initialize();).

However, all I can see in the NHProf is a Session # and the time it took to come up.  But selecting it or any other operations doesn't show me any information about the connection to the database or any information at all in any of the other windows such as:
- Statements, Entities, Session Usage

The Session Factory Statistics only shows Start time, execution time, and thats it.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any custom log4net configuration? Just thinking that might be overwriting NHProf's log4net listener after startup. If you refresh the page (and hence start another session*), does NHProf display another Session start? Also verify that your HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll (or HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll if you're using .NET 4) is the same one as the current version of NHProf.

* I'm assuming that you're using Session-per-Request since this is a web app.